# Adding custom static tags to Spring Kafka consumer metrics

Tags: spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My applicaiton consums same topic name from 2 different clusters
The only metric tag appearing is "spring.id",
needed to add more tags - for example cluster name

tried to implement this
[https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer:~:text=4.1.12.%20Monitoring-,Monitoring%20Listener%20Performance,-Starting%20with%20version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer:%7E:text=4.1.12.%20Monitoring-,Monitoring%20Listener%20Performance,-Starting%20with%20version)

but could not find the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometerTags you can add static tags using the `micrometerTags` properties and dynamic tags using the `micrometerTagsProvider` properties.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So77408974Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So77408974Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so77408974", topics = "so77408974")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so77408974").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, ClusterTag tag) {
        template.setMicrometerTagsProvider(rec -> tag.getClusterTag());
        return args -> {
            template.send("so77408974", "foo");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ContainerCustomizer<String, String, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> containerCustomizer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory, ClusterTag tag) {

        ContainerCustomizer<String, String, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> cust = container -> {
            container.getContainerProperties().setMicrometerTagsProvider(rec -> tag.getClusterTag());
        };
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(cust);
        return cust;
    }

}

@Component
class ClusterTag {

    private final KafkaAdmin admin;

    private Map<String, String> clusterTag;

    public ClusterTag(KafkaAdmin admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getClusterTag() {
        if (this.clusterTag == null) {
            this.clusterTag = Map.of("cluster.id", this.admin.clusterId());
        }
        return this.clusterTag;
    }

}
```

Note: when using versions less than 3.0, you need to use `AdminClient.describeCluster()` to get the cluster id; the `KafkaAdmin` method was added in 3.0.

Comment: Thank You!

However, I could not find a way to add tags to micrometerTags in such a manner that each metric would include the cluster from which the topic consumes.

Comment: I added an example for how to do that.

Comment: Thank You, really appreciate it.
Unfortunately, getClusterTag was not called, although the message was consumed

I m using KAfka stream 4.0.4

Comment: For Kafka Streams, you have to add a `KafkaStreamsMicrometerListener` to the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#streams-micrometer